# What does NODE first = first-> link mean in linked list?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I want to know how a node* variable NODE can be assigned to the data inside the structure?

```
struct node
{
   int info;
   struct node *link;
};

 typedef struct node* NODE;

//IN SOME OTHER FUNCTION
NODE temp,first;
temp = first;
first = first->link; // I WANT HELP WITH THIS LINE.
```

Comment: you assign first to point to the next item in the list, whatever that means in your implementation. First needs not to be null

Comment: [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) can be your friend...or enemy....

Comment: There is "tutorial-style" [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23280743/4142924)

Comment: One thing it means is that someone made your analysis task more difficult by [hiding a pointer-type in a typedef alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: `first` is uninitialized, so `first = first->link` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a linked list you have a node with some information. In every node you have the address of the next node.

```
struct node
{
   int info;           //Information or data which is stored at every node
   struct node *link;  // Address of next node 
};
```

> first = first->link; // I WANT HELP WITH THIS LINE.

If you're done with current node then you may require to access the next node.
In this line you have accessed the next node (`first->link`) of the linked list 
and you are making your next node as `first` (top node).