# How to write a C program for deleting all the nodes before a negative element in a singly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to linked list. Please someone help me with this.
I got a program to delete nodes. I tried to make changes in the following original code. But I am facing some problem.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

 struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
}; 
 void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    new_node->data = new_data; 
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); 
    (*head_ref) = new_node; 
} 

void deleteNode(struct Node **head_ref, int key) 
{ 
    struct Node* temp = *head_ref, *prev; 
    if (temp != NULL && temp->data == key) 
    { 
        *head_ref = temp->next; // Changed head 
        free(temp);          // free old head 
        return; 
    } 
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != key) 
    { 
        prev = temp; 
        temp = temp->next; 
    } 
    if (temp == NULL) return; 
    prev->next = temp->next; 
    free(temp); // Free memory 
} 

void printList(struct Node *node) 
{ 
    while (node != NULL) 
    { 
        printf(" %d ", node->data); 
        node = node->next; 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    /* Start with the empty list */
    struct Node* head = NULL; 

    push(&head, 7); 
    push(&head, -1); 
    push(&head, 3); 
    push(&head, -2); 

    puts("Created Linked List: "); 
    printList(head); 
    deleteNode(&head, 1); 
    puts("\nLinked List after Deletion of 1: "); 
    printList(head); 
    return 0; 
  }
```

What change should I make in the above program to get the work done?
Other programs are also invited.

Comment: I don't think I understand, you want to write a new function or modify the existing one?

Comment: *"I am facing some problem."* - like *what* ? If there is a runtime error, it should be in your posted question. If there is a compile-time error it should be in your posted question. If the output you're expecting isn't what you're actually getting, yep, *both* the expected and actual should *be in your posted question*. What you tried with the above, and where it seems to fall on the floor, is going to be far more productive than just changing your (?) code.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279119/creating-and-understanding-linked-lists-of-structs-in-c/23280743#23280743) will help?

Comment: For Yonlif ...modify the existing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};
struct node* head;

void print(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->link;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
struct node* insert(int x)
{
    node*temp= new node;
    temp->data=x;
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        temp->link=head;
    }
    head=temp;
    return head;
}
    struct node* delete_the_node()
{
    struct node* temp1=head,*temp2;

    while(temp1!=NULL&&temp1->link->data>=0)
    {
        temp2=temp1;
        temp1=temp1->link;
    }
    if(temp1==head)
    {

        temp2=temp1->link;
    temp1->link=NULL;


    }
    else{
    temp2->link=temp1->link;
    temp1->link=NULL;
    free(temp1);}
    return temp2;
}
int main()

{
    cout<<"The linked list is=";
    head=NULL;
    head=insert(3);
    head=insert(-5);
    head=insert(7);
    head=insert(9);
    print(head);
    cout<<"The linked list after deletion=";
    head=delete_the_node();
    print(head);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I made a new program which works. Thanks for all support.